# How to Append CSV file via VBA without reading empty formatted cells

Tags: excel, vba, csv, append

I have a code that is able to Append a range of data in a worksheet to an existing CSV file. However, I noticed that when the existing CSV file contains empty, but formatted cells beyond the end of the data range, the Append function takes into account those empty cells as well.

For example, the existing CSV file has 10 rows of data, while rows 11 to 20 are empty, but has been formatted (e.g. as "dd-mmm-yy"). So when I append the CSV file, the new data is added at row 21 instead of row 11.

Apart from manually deleting rows 11 to 20 in the CSV file, is there a quick fix to this? I have many existing CSV files, so it is not feasible to do the manual way. As to why some of the rows are empty, but formatted, it is due to some earlier amendments that took place.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: *"I have a code"* Please [edit] your question and add that code. We need to see what you have done so far in order to help you with that (see [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

> I **have a code** that is able to Append a range of data in a worksheet to an existing CSV file. However, I noticed that when the existing CSV file contains empty, but formatted cells beyond the end of the data range, the Append function takes into account those empty cells as well.

If you've written that code, it needs to account for the formatted cells you want to ignore.  Let's say you're exchanging data from a .xlsx file to a .csv file and all of this is being done inside the Excel platform.  Then for example, if "General" is the format that works best for you, but some trailing cells in .csv column A, Sheet 1 are not that, then have your code evaluate on a loop whether CSV `Worksheets("Book1").Range("A[whatever row]").NumberFormat = "General"`

Then have your code change the ones that aren't, to General; then proceed with the append.